# Solve $\frac{a^2}{bc}+\frac{b^2}{ca}+\frac{c^2}{ab}+3=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

How can you characterize the set of complex numbers with the same module so that:
$$\frac{a^2}{bc}+\frac{b^2}{ca}+\frac{c^2}{ab}+3=0 ?$$

All my attempts have not led to a clear answer.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a simple algebraic way to got about it... perhaps there is maybe a geometric approach that could help.

Comment: What means "module" here? Absolute value?

Comment: On the contrary, $a^2+b^2+c^2=bc+ca+ab\ne 0$ if and only if $a$, $b$ and $c$ are vertices of equilateral triangle.  Note that $$(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-bc-ca-ab)=a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$$

Answer (score 3):

Since $|a|=|b|=|c|=r\ne 0$, and the $r$ cancels in the given equation, we can choose to write $a=e^{i\alpha}$, $b=e^{i\beta}$, $c=e^{i\gamma}$. Then the given equation becomes $$e^{i(2\alpha-\beta-\gamma)}+e^{i(2\beta-\alpha-\gamma)}+e^{i(2\gamma-\beta-\alpha)}=-3$$ Since the absolute value of each of the terms on the left is $1$, the equation has solution only when each exponential is equal to $-1$.

One might be tempted to say $2\alpha-\beta-\gamma=\pi$ and similar for the other two, but the system does not have solution. The correct way is to say $2\alpha-\beta-\gamma=\pi+2k\pi$, where $k$ in an integer. Writing all three equations
$$2\alpha-\beta-\gamma=\pi+2k_1\pi\\
2\beta-\alpha-\gamma=\pi+2k_2\pi\\
2\gamma-\alpha-\beta=\pi+2k_1\pi
$$
Subtracting any two we get that the angle between $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ is multiple of $2\pi/3$, so $a,b, c$ are the vertices of an equilateral triangle